# Extracting an image from its background

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, webgl

I am trying to build a hobby application which would render people's Facebook conversations as a cartoon strip, the problem is that I need cartoonish images of the actors in the conversation. I was thinking of extracting the photo of a person from his desktop profile and rendering a cartoonish version of that image.

Is there a way to extract an image from its background using webGL or some other way?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a really broad one, because feature extraction from an image isn't that straightforward. WebGL is just a graphics representation tool and not a SDK, so you might be asking the wrong crowd here (also, because you're targetting Facebook users, WebGL isn't a good tool for the trade because it wouldn't support Internet Explorer's users).

However, something that may or may not help you are [Edge detection algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) that could help to build a solution for you and a [Posterization filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterization) could help you out too. These effects could be achieved using Canvas and a simple [Convolution matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution).

Comment: hey thanks ...actlly I might have found somewhat of a solution in http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#bg_remove

Comment: As I understand from my research there is no perfect way to do this for all cases and it depends on transparency of the background etc.
I also saw in a seperate stackoverflow question that someone suggested Amazon Mechanical Turk for a similar kind of application

Comment: ImageMagic only works with matte backgrounds or predefined ones. If you are intending to use it to mask random background from photos on Facebook that won't work. Also, if you're going to use something outside the browser take a look at OpenCV, it works very well and is very powerful